# Как отследить переход по браузерной вкладке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделал простое оповещение о новых сообщениях(мигает title)

Теперь нужно реализовать чтение, то есть чтобы title переставал мигать, когда пользователь возвращается на вкладку

Нашел решение

```
window.onfocus = function () {alert(документ снова активен);}
```

Все работает, но метод вызывается не прерывно, а нужно 1 раз

Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
var exit = 0;
window.onblur = function () {exit = 1}
if(exit == 1) {
  window.onfocus = function () {alert('документ снова активен'); exit = 0;}
}
```

Есть ли более щадящее решение?

Мигание title

```
                    var newTxt="Новое сообщение";
                    var oldTxt=document.title;

                    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='shortcut icon']") || document.createElement('link');
                    link.type = 'image/png';
                    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';

                    function migalka(){
                        if(count_alert_message.text() >= 1) {

                            if (document.title == oldTxt) {
                                document.title = newTxt;
                                link.href = '/favicon1.png';
                            } else {
                                document.title = oldTxt;
                                link.href = '/favicon.png';
                            }
                        } else {
                            document.title = oldTxt;
                            link.href = '/favicon.png';
                        }
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
                    }
                    var timer = setInterval(migalka,800);
```

Comment: 1) Покажите что за "мигалку" вы используете. 2) Попробуйте стандартное `window.flush()` - возможно оно вам больше понравится.

Comment: @nick_n_a Обновил вопрос, по остановке мигания у меня вопросов нет, мне главное отследить переход обратно на вкладку, либо проверку, что у пользователя открыта страница. Можно поподробней о `window.flush()` не нашел информации

Comment: У  `setInterval` есть антипод.  `clearinterval(timer)`  делайте вызов, когда мигание "закончилось" https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: мигайте через таймаут `setTimeout`. внутри функции мигания в самом конце НЕ добавляйте очередное мигание, если флаг выхода выставлен.

Comment: @Lexx918 Как мигать таймаутом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFocus() {
  window.onfocus = null;
  // перестаем мигать
}
function myBlur() {
  window.onfocus = myFocus;
  // начинаем мигать
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как мигать таймаутом?

Первый раз вызываете функцию мигания там где раньше запускали интервалы. А повторные запуски производите внутри самой функции пока не получите флаг остановки как уже делали это раньше.

В итоге не придётся думать про способ остановки, не придётся хранить в переменной сам интервал и не придётся беспокоиться о слишком часто идущих кадрах: ведь с таймаутом вы запускаете подготовку следующего слайда только после рендера текущего.

```
function migalka(){
    // тут ваши обычные действия с анимацией
    // ...

    if (!exit) {
        setTimeout(migalka, 800);
    }
}
migalka();
```

Если сама функция мигалки не нужна в глобале, плюс хочется красиво запустить её не указывая имени явно, можно чуть сократить определение и сразу вызвать так:

```
(function migalka(){ /* тут тело функции из примера выше */ })();
```